# Using just strtotime, 0 am first day of this month in PHP?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
echo mydate(strtotime('1 am first day of this month'));
```

Above works with result `2017-10-01 01:00:00`, but I have difficulty to do it for 0 am. Neither `24am, 24pm, 0pm, first second` works.

Comment: What's mydate?  My PHP never heard of that one!

Comment: @Nic. mydate means that is my date function, mine!

Comment: Ok so how do we test - debug your code without yourdate?  @John Conde provided you an answer with date(), and it will probably work in your context, but next question, provide full code or use PHP we can try and test on our side to help you ;-)

Comment: @Nic. Please, that is obvious if you look at the context.

Comment: @Nic I don't think mydate is the problem here..

Comment: Midnight is 12 am, and midday is 12 pm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `midnight`:

```
echo mydate(strtotime('midnight first day of this month'));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/888226)

Comment: Alternatively, `12 am`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `DateTime` for date and time manipulations,

`$date = new DateTime('midnight first day of this month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

or if there is need to UnixTimestamp : `$date->format('U');`
or `echo $date->getTimestamp();`